# Generate Signed APK Wizard generates APK with debugging enabled

Tags: android, apk

So after I do generate signed APK wizard in android studio I get an APK file.  But when I try to upload the file to android developer console I get an error saying the file is debuggable.  So my question is how can I get Android Studio to generate an APK that I can upload to the android market?

Answer (score 1):

> Support for a true debug build. Developers no longer need to add the
>   android:debuggable attribute to the  tag in the manifest
>   — the build tools add the attribute automatically. In Eclipse/ADT, all
>   incremental builds are assumed to be debug builds, so the tools insert
>   android:debuggable="true". When exporting a signed release build, the
>   tools do not add the attribute. In Ant, a ant debug command
>   automatically inserts the android:debuggable="true" attribute, while
>   ant release does not. If android:debuggable="true" is manually set,
>   then ant release will actually do a debug build, rather than a release
>   build.

remove the android:debuggable="true" tag from the manifest file and generate the signed apk file with the same keystore generated before.

for more details, [see here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Answer (score 1):

Using Android Studio 0.3.7:

First make sure you have into you `<application>` entry of the `AndroidManifest.xml` the following entry `android:debuggable="false"`

Then go to the **Build** menu option, and choose "**Generate Signed APK**". Create a key store or use an existing one, click "Next", change destination if desired. and decide if you want to use ProGuard or not, then click "Finish". And you have now you APK ready for production :).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to have this in androidmanifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:debuggable="true"
    . . .>
</application>
```